# Resetting visited colour

Tags: html, css, hover, hyperlink

I need to have the colour of the links to change on hover but go back to original once clicked, the code I currently use stops the hover from changing once a link has been clicked.

```
<div id="nav1"><a href="clients.html">/Clients</a></div>

#nav1 {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Gill Sans";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 10pt;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#nav1 a:link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav1 a:hover {
    color: #e8138b;
    text-decoration: overline;
}
#nav1 a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your declaration of `a:hover` after `a:visited`.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `:hover` styles below the `:visited` styles. They have equal selector specificity, so the last styles takes effect for a link that is `:hover` and `:visited`.

By the way, if you wanted a separate style altogether, you can use `:hover:visited`.

Comment: I'm just imaging all the different ways IE would break when it sees multiple pseudo elements. It would be like throwing bricks in a glass store.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
#nav1 a:link,
#nav1 a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav1 a:hover {
  color: #e8138b;
  text-decoration: overline;
}
```